# Compound Interest algorithm producing weird answer? (5-7 hours of troubleshooting already)

Tags: c++

Very new to C++. Doing my best to get a good handle on this.

The extra couts after the read statements were for troubleshooting purposes to make sure it was actually reading user input.

I feel like this is a dumb question but iv been scouring the forums to find something similar to my issue.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this program to start calculating the correct interest. When comparing to an online interest calculator it comes up with a very different number than what the program is calculating.

I have spent tons of hours troubleshooting this and texting different algorithms but I have yet to come out on-top. I dont normally like asking for help because I learn by struggling through something but this one is throwing me for a loop...

So I think I might either be having an issue with the libraries I am using or a calculation error. I know the code is a bit messy and I am learning how to clean it up but as for now I just want to get the code calculating compound interest based off of user input. I have added comments to explain what each section of code does to help with my messiness.

I dont believe its a syntax error but with the way I am either using a few of the commas in the algorithm or my parentheses are somehow wrong.

the formula I am using is,

> A = P (1 + r/n)^(nt)
>
> Amount = principle (1 + interest rate/times compounded)^(rate, times
>   compounded)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double rate;
    double time;
    double principle;
    double amount;
    double amount2;

//Asking for the amount of money that the user would like to invest

    cout << "What is the amount of money you would like to invest? ";

    cin >> principle;
    cout << principle << endl;

//Asking for the interest rate that will be compounded annually

    cout << "What is the interest rate you would like to calculate? "; 
    cin >> rate;

//interest rate divided by 100 so it can be multiplied by the principle and the amount of time the money will be invested later in code.

    rate /= 100;
    cout << rate << endl;

//Asking for the amount of years that the user will invest. 
cout << "How many times would you like to compound your money? ";

    cin >> time;
    cout << time << endl;

//calculation for amount of money that will be made after all user input is input

    amount2 = pow(rate, time);
    cout << amount2 << endl;

    amount = (principle * (1 + rate/time), amount2); 


//Output data after all user data is input and calculated. 

    cout << "Your will have "; cout << amount; cout << " dollars in 
    interest! "<< endl;  

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: C != C++. C does not have `namespace std;` or `cout`. Please use only tags that are actually relevant to your question, and don't add those that just seem familiar or similar. Tags have specific meaning and purpose here. You've also not explained a problem or asked a question. What **specifically** can we help you with? Please [edit] to explain, as well as providing sample input and the output you expect to obtain from that input.

Comment: Define what "correct interest" means to you.

Comment: At what point do you get an unexpected output?

Comment: `amount = (principle * (1 + rate/time), amount2); ` What is that supposed to do? The comma looks out of place.

Comment: First, I'd move all the math to a function. Having it scattered around the entire program is messy and makes it harder to test, since it forces you to rely on `cin` to get input.

Comment: `final_balance = initial_balance * pow(yearly_rate / yearly_compounding_count + 1, yearly_compounding_count * year_count)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
amount = (principle * (1 + rate/time), amount2);
```

Does absolutely nothing with `principle * (1 + rate/time)`. That expression is evaluated, and then the results are discarded, leaving `amount` to be assigned the value in `amount2`. I assume you were trying to call a function with those two expressions as parameters.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its
>   result is discarded, and its side effects are completed before
>   evaluation of the expression `E2` begins.

Now that we have your formula:

```
A = P (1 + r/n)^(nt)
```

> ```
> Amount = principle (1 + interest rate/times compounded)^(rate * times compounded)
> ```

I am not certain you are computing the formula you have listed above, and note the correction to the second line, where I replace the comma with multiplication.

```
amount2 = pow(rate, time);
```

Computes `rate^time`, where you should have:

```
amount2 = 1 * time; // Where one is the times compounded per period (year)
```

So that your other line can read:

```
amount = principle * pow((1 + rate, amount2);
```

Because you are compounding once per year, you are dividing rate by 1, not by the number of years. By the same token, amount2 is now strictly equal to time;

Comment: So what would I use in its place? When i remove the comma it wont compile. The reason I even have amount 2 as a variable was to help split the math up to make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: what are you trying to calculate?  write down the formula.

Comment: @MikelF my output with your edited code is still throwing a super weird output. Its giving me about 12 dollars in interest if I use 5000 for principle, 5% for interest rate, and compounding it 100 times. The algorithm looks correct so im at a loss as to where in my program the issue could be. Im using visual studio also, not sure if that matters.